# get values from jboss property file

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse

```
protected void sss()
{ 

    //InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/app.properties");

    try(FileReader reader=new FileReader("src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/app.properties")){
    Properties pro=new Properties();
            pro.load(reader);
            String url=pro.getProperty("ConfirmProductMasterDataStatus");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

I want to access property file which is in "**src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/app.properties**"

Answer (score 1):

if you have Class that in the same folder as your property file you can do it like that:

```
    InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("app.properties.properties");
    Properties pro=new Properties();
    try {
        pro.load(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String url=pro.getProperty("ConfirmProductMasterDataStatus");
```

It's hard for me to give you a more general structure without knowing the structure of your project 
I guess your Main is at src/main so you can do:

```
    InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/OSGI-INF/app.properties");
    Properties pro=new Properties();
    try {
        pro.load(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String url=pro.getProperty("ConfirmProductMasterDataStatus");
```

Note that if you change the structure of the project you should remember to note that the path is still correct

Comment: yes, my main class is at src/main/java    and prop file is in src/main/resources

Comment: when i add that code its ask me to add library to main   says import (org,apche,camel),(org,apche,camel,main )... and so on

Comment: the imports are
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;
if your main src/main/java and your prop is src/main/resources you shuold do:
 InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("../resources /app.properties");

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load it by using the classpath path:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("OSGI-INF/app.properties");
Properties pro=new Properties();
pro.load(reader);
```

Comment: You need the absolute path to the file and load it with `new FileInputStream("<PATH_TO_FILE>")`. If your path is available in a JBoss system property you can load the path (e.g. the jboss/server path) with `System.getProperty("jboss.server.base.dir");`